# Gizmo missing in version 2.90.1

Tags: tools

I'm in version 2.90.1 and my gizmo (manipulator) is missing. Does anyone know how to get it back? I checked and the check box is checked. Restarting didn't resolve anything.
Does anybody have a clue how to get it back?

Comment: could you provide more context, and maybe some of your settings that you have enabled.  It's hard to know how to fix your problem if we don't have an idea of what is causing it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this button to toggle gizmos off and on.

[image]

You can choose the kind of manipulator you want to enable:

[image]

Note that the gizmo will show at the origin of the **selected** object. For multiple objects the gizmo will show at the median.

To move rotate and scale, a different kind of gizmo will appear depending on the chosen tool.

[image]