# Blender 2.92, Show gizmo move Keybind

Tags: shortcut

I'm unable to find the show gizmo move keybind. So what I specifically want is to see the XYZ-arrows when I press G to move, just like they show up when I press Move on the toolbar to the left.

Apparently it was shift+space+g in Blender 2.8.
When I try it, shift+space starts some animation frame instead.

I searched in the keymaps but theres nothing relevant on "gizmo", so that leaves me overwhelmed.

I found this thread but its not the answer [Gizmo missing in version 2.90.1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202892/gizmo-missing-in-version-2-90-1/202914#202914)

Comment: Space (pressed on it's own) starts the animation playing. With shift depressed, press space to bring up the tools menu. then pressing  G will invoke the move gizmo .

Comment: Not for me. My Space is set to search. Shift+space starts animation playing.

Comment: what shortcut do you see if you hover over tool as suggested in answer below?

Comment: None, no shortcuts in any tooltip.

Comment: Even if I changed space from Search to Tools, I still play with Shift+Space. 
If I at the same time remove the keybind for Play Animation (which says Shift+Space) it's still not solved.

Comment: Ok, what do you get for _`Prefs > Keymaps > Search > Name`_    search for "Toolbar"  For me I get the default Shift Space (under Window context)  _Could answer re how to set up this keymap?_

Comment: What I refered to above is the Spacebar Action, which I have set to Search.

anyway, well if I search for "Toolbar" I only find "Fallback tool pie menu" which is Alt+W.

Comment: btw to turn on tooltips _`Prefs > Interface > Display`_  Did you bring keymaps over from a previous version of blender?

Comment: Here is the keymap https://pasteall.org/media/1/7/1706b91868968a7093908e096558c244.png  to bring up toolbar menu.

Comment: No, I am a new user since less than a month back. 
I have User Tooltips already checked. I tried the Python Tooltips but that made it just look like actual code. 
It says I can force to show if I hold Alt but that doesnt work regardless of checked or not.
Without changing anything yet, this is what mine looks like >> https://imgur.com/a/exA75eW

Comment: And this is what I get if I search for toolbar, how come you can find it but I cannot? >> https://imgur.com/a/H7E22Dh
are you using another version than 2.92?

Comment: I get same as my image above for both 2.91 and 2.92 on ubuntu. Showed image because you can easily add the keymap.

Comment: ok thanks Ill see how I want to set it up. Apparently its due to me using Right click. Its quite defeatening how everything in Blender seem to change over just 1 or 2 versions.
And the keybind dont show in the tooltip but Ill just accept it doesnt work for me.

Comment: Bit the bullet at 2.8 and started fresh with new defaults. Was hard to get head around left click select at first, but... must admit always thought it should have been this way round in first place as it matches most software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If it's missing add a new keymap.**

By default <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> brings up the toolbar menu. Can search for it's keymap via *`Prefs > Keymaps > Search > Name`*  "Toolbar"

[image]

As you can see, for me it is there, but for you it isn't, in which case will add a new one.

At the bottom of the window context, click on the add new button.

[image]

Fill in the properties as above (*Bit silly as for me as above is literally as above...*)

Should now be able to press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and bring up the toolbar menu,

[image]

and if so save preferences.

Comment: Ah now we talking! Now as I added my own keybind for "wm.toolbar" then also "toolbar" can be searched for. So this means the toolbar does not have a keybind with the Right click configure. I had to remove the Play Animate which is no problem. 
Im very content with this. The key was the wm.toolbar, that part I would not figure out even if I knew how to change an existing keybind. Excellent. Vielen dank, grazie, kiitos and thank you.

Its too bad I cannot give you my upvote.

Comment: You could mark this answer as accepted, that helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to turn on and off the move tool, by default is by Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> , <kbd>G</kbd>.

If you don't see anything, hover your mouse over the move tool and you will see the shortcut appear

[image]

Comment: I thought about that too but none of my tooltips show the shortcut like yours does.
Is it because I use Right for select? Does that change so many things in the keybinds?
If I could find this gizmo in the Keymap, I could see it. But I dont know how to find it as mentioned

Comment: I changed Right to Left but that didnt change the supposed outcome of the keybind.

Comment: try with factory reset... File > Defaults > Load Factory settings and also inside the preference settings... Edit > Preferences > click the three lines in the bottom left corner > Load Factory Preferences

Comment: Okay this helps but only for Left click setting. As soon as I go back to Right click, things change. 
So while it answers, im not satisfied but I dont blame you instead Blender.